# php if array has another array

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox, sub-array

Seems weird matter. Is there any way to detect `array` that contains `sub-array` in php, such `parent-child` concept in `css, jquery`. I want to insert data only if `array` has `subarray`

Dynamic Menu

```
<?php
    if(){ //loop starts
?>  
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="menu[]" value="<?php echo $row['value']?>"> <?php echo $row['title'];
            <ul>
                <?php
                    if(){ //loop starts
                ?>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="submenu[]" value="<?php echo $row1['value']?>"><?php echo $row1['subtitle'];
                </li>;
                }?>

            </ul>
    </li>
}?>
```

Output

```
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="menu[]" value="vehicle">
    <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="submenu[]" value="car"></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="submenu[]" value="bike"></li>
     </ul>
</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="menu[]" value="sport"></li>
```

upload.php

```
$data = explode("," ,$_POST["menu"]); 
$subdata = explode("," ,$_POST["submenu"]);
foreach ($data AS $key => $menu){
    if(){         // This Menu has subarray

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your case you have to do easy with following method

```
<li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="menu[0][]" value="vehicle">
        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="submenu[0][]" value="car"></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="submenu[0][]" value="bike"></li>
         </ul>
    </li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="menu[1][]" value="sport"></li>
        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="submenu[1][]" value="cricket"></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="submenu[1][]" value="football"</li>
         </ul>
```

then from a backend, you can do like

```
foreach($_POST['menu'] as $key=>$val) {
        if(is_array($val) && count($val)) {
           //do action
        }
}
```

Comment: seems it will easy and best answer, but I have dynamic list generated using loop , Please help how to increase number i.e. `menu[0][], menu[1][]....menu[5][]` as output in your answer. Please see my updated question I put my dynamic code

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`is_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) function to see if a variable is an array, if you want to recursively check then you can use [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) with [`is_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) as the callback.

**Note:** If you use `array_walk_recursive`, it will run the callback on items that are non array, so you could compare that which is returned from `array_walk_recursive` against the original array to find out all those items which are arrays. However, `is_array` seems like the easier option.

**Live Example**

[Repl](https://repl.it/repls/UnnaturalRedundantSearchservice)

Comment: thanks, I had used is_array function, but it considers one's `sub array` as `common subarray`. For example in my question one menu has submenu, another hasnot. `if(is_array($data)){}` is inserting data in both array that contain `subarray` and `non subarray`. I'm new in `array_walk_recursive`. Please provide any demo using this, hope this will helps